# Fragment onActivityResult method on executing calls activity onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

In my fragment I have started startActivityforresult intent for photo capture.I have overridden onActivityResult callback method in fragment class. I have implemented onActivityResult callback in main activity for some other intent. My problem is fragment onActivityResult after execution calls activities onActivityResult method and returns null pointer exception. 
Fragment onactivityresult method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {
        prof_bitmap = null;
        if (requestCode == 0) 
        {
            Log.e("" ,"entered activity Result Code 0");
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            if (photoUri != null) 
            {
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                        photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Log.e("" ,"File Path" +filePath);
                prof_bitmap = setImage(filePath);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == 1) 
        {
            Log.e("" ,"entered activity Result Code 1");
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            prof_bitmap = bitmap;
            Log.e("" ,"entered activity Result Code 1"+bitmap);
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity onActivityResult

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("" ,"called onActivityResult in main");
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

how to call only fragment onactivityresult method?

MY Logcat

Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/222 (has extras) }} to activity {com.mobiotics.tvbuddydemo/com.mobiotics.tvbuddydemo.TVBuddyMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Remove super call in fragment

Comment: See this link may help you:https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/onactivityresult-in-fragment/

Answer (score 9):

If you have onActivityResult defined in your Activity, you can't skip it and go directly to the Fragment. You can however redirect it to the Fragment if the Activity does not know how to handle it. Use unique requestCodes to differentiate between who handles the result.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    boolean processed = true;

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            // Something
        } else if (requestCode == 1) {
            // Something
        } else {
            processed = false;
        }
    } else { // Error
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            // Handle error 
        } else {
            processed = false;
        }
    }

    if (!processed) {
        fragment1.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fragment2.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure to call getActivity().startActivityForResult() from your fragment and not simply using this.startActivityForResult()

```
public void something(Intent intent) {
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent);
    // or if you are using SherlockActionBar/Support package
    getSupportActivity().startActivityForResult(intent);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That means you are calling startActivityForResult() from your Fragment incorrectly. You need to call getActivity().startActivityForResult(). I will update the answer to include this.

Comment: i have implemented the above but getting failure in delivering result infoerror null pointer exception

Comment: pls check above for logcat

Comment: Why did I get fragment's `onActivityResult` called before root activity's?

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the line `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in your fragment `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: If you exit/close the activity, the activity method `onActivityResult()` must be called. I would suggest you to remove the fragment method and use only `onActivityResult()` by activity.

Answer (score 1):

`public void onActivityResult` is called when the `Activity` you started with `startActivityForResult` is finished calling `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

The onActivityResult in Activity will be called first, you should not remove processing the result in Activity but do what you want via checking the requestCode.

Answer (score 0):

I aslo face this problem.

Calling of an activity from fragment

((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 100);

here "context" from FragmentActivity. Now the result comes in FargmentActivity onActivityResult method. to switch this result you have to declare a static variable of fragment class in fragmetn activity class.

```
static ActivityUploadPhotos activityUploadPhotos;

...
ActivityUploadPhotos f = new ActivityUploadPhotos();
ActivityHome.activityUploadPhotos=f;
......

if(activityUploadPhotos!=null)
{
           activityUploadPhotos.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```