# Retrieve data from onActivityResult (Fragment class)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, onactivityresult

onActivityResult (Activity class)

```html
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
 
 if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        Data.desiredaddress = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

}
```

onActivityResult (Fragment class)

```html
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     
     if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
      
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
 
            
   Cursor cursor1 = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor1.moveToFirst();
 
            int columnIndex = cursor1.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            Data.desiredaddress = cursor1.getString(columnIndex);
            
            cursor1.close();

        } 
}
```

My problem :

- The value of Data.desiredaddress change if it is modify in activity class but it did not change in  fragment class.

can someone help me with this.

- the app has no error and it didn't crash.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried debugging whether it is going inside onActivityResult or not??

Comment: See this link may help you:https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/onactivityresult-in-fragment/

Answer (score 0):

After i go through some other question , i found out that the reason for this is because onActivityResult (parent activity) will not be ignored even if i called onActivityResult from fragment class.

Thank you to @Aswin Rajendiran for the idea.

here is the link for further explaination : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16434914/4148255